# Including Eigen

Tags: c++, eclipse, eigen

I've included the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) headers in a C++ project in Eclipse. When I try to build I get this error:

```
Symbol 'Eigen' could not be resolved    Semantic Error
```

From what I understand, this is a linker error, but Eigen is a header-only project and thus has no library to link against. The code that throws the error follows the basic tutorial they  provide, and the offending snippet looks like this:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;
```

What am I doing wrong? If it helps, I'm running this on Linux. Thanks.

Comment: Did you link the corresponding library?

Comment: @MelNicholson: Eigen has no corresponding library. It's header-only.

Comment: I'm not having `Unresolved inclusion` errors, so presumably I can find the headers, I just can't use them for some reason.

Comment: In the snippet the `#include <Eigen/Dense>` does not throw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was fiddling around and found that telling the Indexer to index unused headers resolved my problem.

[image]

Thanks for being on the ball guys. Kind of sorry I stumbled upon it myself.

Answer (score 5):

Check the compiler gets the correct include path. For example, the Eigen library headers may be installed in `/usr/include/eigen3`, so when compiling you'd have to give the compiler the flag `-I /usr/include/eigen3`.

Answer (score 3):

Eigen normally gets installed by most distributions to `/usr/include/eigen2` and/or `/usr/include/eigen3` or similar. Verify where the headers have been installed, as you need to add that path as an additional include path in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put the headers directly in your project, it makes eclipse horribly slow and sometimes even shows warnings or even (wrong) errors. Instead, you should put the library somewher on disk and link to it (set the propper include directory) via project propperties -> c/c++ General -> GNU C++ -> Add -> File system -> Eigens root folder (where you extracted it to)