# include <Eigen/Dense> succeed, include <Eigen> failed

Tags: c++, include, eigen

My question is similar to this 5 years old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593350/including-eigen).

I can successfully compile it if I use the following code:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
//#include <boost/serialization/array_wrapper.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>

int main(){
        std::cout<<"asfserea"<<std::endl;
        boost::gregorian::date d(boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day());
        std::cout << d.year() << d.month() <<d.day() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

But I got errors after I changed annotation from `#include <Eigen/Dense>` to `#include <Eigen>`, from `#include <boost/date_time...>` to `#include <boost/serialization...>`:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to change the headers if your code compiles in its current state?

Comment: I cloned a project from github and in his file, he used #include<Eigen> and then use typedef Eigen::Matrix.etc

Comment: Based on your comment, you have a misunderstanding. Changing the #include does not impact on the need for qualifying `Matrix` with `Eigen::`.

Comment: It is preferable to `#include <Eigen/Eigen>` rather than adding the `Eigen` subfolder to your include path.

Answer (score 3):

File you are looking for is `<Eigen/Eigen>`. If you want to include `<Eigen>`, you should add correct folder to your include path.

For `array_wrapper.hpp`, you need newer version of Boost. At least version 1.67.0 has this file.

Comment: My boost version is 1_67_0 and I do have array_wrapper.hpp in it.

Comment: @jack If `#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>` works, I presume you already have Boost in your include path, so `#include <boost/serialization/array_wrapper.hpp>` should work as well. Are you sure your include path leads to correct version of Boost, rather than an older version that does not have `array_wrapper.hpp`?

Comment: I included boost_1_67_0/stage/lib into CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH, I included boost_1_67_0 into PATH

Answer (score 3):

When you `#include <Eigen>`, your compiler looks at the directories that you have told it about, for a file named `Eigen`. It only finds a *folder* named `Eigen`, and *within that folder* there are files `Eigen` and `Dense`. It *does not look* inside that folder.

If you change your compilers parameters to include the `Eigen` folder (rather than it's parent), you can `#include <Eigen>` and `#include <Dense>`. Alternatively, you can keep your include directories as they are, and prepend `Eigen/` to all the Eigen includes